# designing a roll rate transition martix table in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix

i have this assignment and am stuck in designing a roll rate transition matrix table in python the assignment was as follows:
1)Design a roll rate table transition matrix table for loans. Describe how you would approach the task of deriving the roll rate from the retro data. Fill in the table with realistic example rates. Feel free to use common sense or a data-driven approach to derive the examples.

So I did:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import rand
np.random.seed(50)
```

and it gave me a set dataframe matrix but random numbers but now i have few  questions

1. All columns are suppose to add up to 1 or 100
2. The transition matrix is suppose to line up as an identity matrix
   now how do you do this in python ?

Comment: This is better than your first attempt at asking this question, but you still have to provide more info. It would help to define some terms- not everyone knows what a "roll rate" is. If you don't know how to code it, at least describe in words what you _would_ do, so people can help point you in  the right direction.

Comment: Regards Pault myself i dont know clearly what a roll rate table is all i know is its just a transition marix for a markov chain with payment dates and all, as you can see from the work it is to design the roll rate table as they said lets just use common sense or data-driven appriach thats why i used random number as follows:
from numpy.random import rand
np.random.seed(50)

Answer (score 3):

Loan performance is often provided in a single field as a string. So if it is you'll have to break that out. Below is a dataframe representing 6 loans.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
  "CCCCCC", 
  "CCCC3C", 
  "C3363C", 
  "6669F",
  "CC3CC3",
  "69R"
], columns=["history"])
```

If the strings are uneven in length, you have to pad them with some value. Below I consider 6 months history

```
mo_history = 6
df = df.history.str.pad(mo_history,fillchar="X").str[-mo_history:]
df

0    CCCCCC
1    CCCC3C
2    C3363C
3    X6669F
4    CC3CC3
5    XXX69R
Name: history, dtype: object
```

Split it up into periods

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(x)))
df

    0   1   2   3   4   5
0   C   C   C   C   C   C
1   C   C   C   C   3   C
2   C   3   3   6   3   C
3   X   6   6   6   9   F
4   C   C   3   C   C   3
5   X   X   X   6   9   R
```

Break out the transitions and exclude those that were filled

```
df_trans = pd.DataFrame(columns=["mo1","mo2"])

for c1 in range(len(df.columns) - 1):
    c2 = c1 + 1
    trans = pd.concat([df[c1],df[c2]],axis=1)
    trans.columns = ["mo1","mo2"]
    df_trans = pd.concat([df_trans, trans],ignore_index=True)

df_trans = df_trans[(df_trans["mo1"] != "X") & (df_trans["mo2"] != "X")]
df_trans[:5]

    mo1 mo2
0   C   C
1   C   C
2   C   3
4   C   C
6   C   C
```

We have to get all the possible states

```
states = set(df_trans.values.flatten())
states

{'C', '3', '6', '9', 'F', 'R'}
```

Create the roll table and populate with zeros

```
num_states = len(states)
roll_rates = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros([num_states, 
num_states]),columns=states,index=states)
roll_rates

    C   3   6   9   F   R
C   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
3   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
6   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
9   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
F   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
R   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

Finally you populate the table

```
for s1 in states:
    for s2 in states:
        num_match = sum((df_trans["mo1"] == s1) & (df_trans["mo2"] == s2))
        num_all = sum(df_trans["mo1"] == s1)
        if num_all > 0:
            roll_rates.loc[s2,s1] = num_match / float(num_all)
roll_rates

    C       3     6     9     F     R
C   0.71    0.6   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
3   0.29    0.2   0.2   0.0   0.0   0.0
6   0.00    0.2   0.4   0.0   0.0   0.0
9   0.00    0.0   0.4   0.0   0.0   0.0
F   0.00    0.0   0.0   0.5   0.0   0.0
R   0.00    0.0   0.0   0.5   0.0   0.0
```

Note that the last two columns (F and R) have zero values because they never appear in state 1. You can exclude them to meet your condition of all the columns summing up to one.